# Run js function only after page completes submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I've a modal dialog in Javascript I want to show up but only after the page is completed submit ie after page submit. 
I've tried jquery callback but doesn't work. 
Any help is appreciated.... Regards

Comment: Um, the page submits? You can not run JavaScript from the page if the entire page si replaced. If it is an Ajax call, than it is a different story.

Comment: Hi,  the page is Not replaced but it stays displayed after submit. Iam not navigating anywhere but I only want to display the modal popup on top.

Comment: So how does the form submit? You need to show some stuff.....